# What is specifically meant by t[1|2].micro AWS instances having low I/O bandwidth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is meant by this low I/O bandwidth constraint? Does Amazon give a lower priority to I/O operations for t[1|2].micro instances?

What I'm asking specifically is, does Amazon limit the I/O intentionally or is the low I/O a result of the limited resources of the t[1|2].micro instance? From what I've read on Amazon, AWS EBS-based magnetic drives have IOPS between 40-200; does the t[1|2].micro instance then provide lower transport capacity per I/O operation?

This is entirely confusing to me b/c a 7200 RPM drive has IOPS between 75-100 on a desktop computer. Why then would IOPS between 40-200 on a t1.micro instance w/an attached EBS-based magnetic disk be considered low?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

EBS volumes are not a single drive. Generally the best way to think of them is more along the lines of a raid volume.

So, instances are shared on host hardware. Which means that the bandwidth available to the EBS volume is shared among all instances on the host. Micro instances get the lowest priority of all instances sizes.

With a micro instance, even if you have a volume capable of 200 IOPS, depending how noisy your neighbors are, you may not even get close to that.